# Use inmemory database for testing my DAO with Play Framework

Tags: playframework, integration-testing, datasource

I'm new to developing with Play framework. My production DB is a MySQL instance. I'm trying to test my DAO class using a H2 in memory database instance.
The relevant section of my application.conf is:

```
db {
default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/production?useSSL=false"
default.username=root
default.password="**********"

test.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
test.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false"
test.username=root
test.password="**********"}
```

My DAO class is like this:

```
public class EventDaoImpl implements EventDao {

private Database database;

@Inject
public EventDaoImpl(Database database) {
    this.database = database;
}
```

My test class is like this:

```
public class EventDaoImplIntegrationTest {

@Inject
private EventDao eventDao;
@Before
public void setup() {
    Module testModule = new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bind(EventDao.class).to(EventDaoImpl.class);
        }
    };

    GuiceApplicationBuilder builder = new GuiceApplicationLoader()
            .builder(new ApplicationLoader.Context(Environment.simple()))
            .overrides(testModule);
    Guice.createInjector(builder.applicationModule()).injectMembers(this);

    //Helpers.start(application);
}

@After
public void teardown() {
    //Helpers.stop(application);
}
```

My question is how can I tell Play that I want to use the test datasource for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach:

1. I have test application-test.conf which consists of:

   ```
   include "application.conf"    
   # now override variables that we would like to from application.conf
   db.default.driver="org.h2.Driver"
   db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test"
   ...
   ```
2. When creating GuiceApplication I do following:

   ```
   Config config = ConfigFactory.load("application-test");
   app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().configure(config).build()
   ```

Cannot promise that this is the most optimal approach, but it works just fine. Hope it helps you